# How to rank values inside of a function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two columns of values and I want to find the correlation of their ranks. Is there a way to do this without first explicitly calculating the ranks in new columns? Something like `=CORREL(RANK.AVG(column A), RANK.AVG(column B))`? Basically something like the example below, without having to first create the `Rank A` and `Rank B` columns.

```
-------------------------------
|  A  |  B  | Rank A | Rank B |
-------------------------------
| 3.3 | 2.1 |    2   |    2   |
| 1.7 | 1.4 |    1   |    1   |
| 4.1 | 7.2 |    4   |    4   |
| 3.7 | 9.0 |    3   |    5   |
| 5.6 | 4.1 |    5   |    3   |
-------------------------------
=CORREL(Rank A, Rank B) = 0.6
```

Comment: Try this: =CORREL(RANK.AVG(A1:A5,A1:A5),RANK.AVG(B1:B5,B1:B5))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

[image]

In the screenshot is non-english delimeter (`;`) used.

```
=CORREL(RANK.AVG(Table1[Rank A],Table1[Rank A],1),RANK.AVG(Table1[Rank B],Table1[Rank B],1))
```

In older Excel versions the formula must be confirmed as an [array formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) (confirmed by `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`).

See [Example in Excel Online](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArVkYVSHnABFiixxfEX34CR094N3?e=6qu8KF).